# How to use new Jqueryui Autocomplete with PHP+MySQL in a SIMPLE way

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have searched almost a month everyday for this. In some cases they use the $.ajax way, in others the $.post way. In jqueryui demo page for autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ you can see they have a simple understandable way of grabbing the data to show it to the user. Now here comes my problem. Am trying to do a simple, short way of grabbing a list of names from a mysql table. this is what i have right now:

JS

$("#usuario").autocomplete({
source: "search.php",
minLength: 3,
select: function( event, ui ) {}
});

PHP

> $nameser = $_POST['usuario'];
>
> $names = '';
>
> $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM characters WHERE name LIKE '%$nameser%'");
>
> while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $names .= "$row[name]"."
> "; }
>
> echo $names;

if i send info from the input box to php it returns the search pattern answer correctly But how do i attach the returned information to the autocomplete in a simple way.

The jquery documentation does not provide a simple way of doing it to a php remote file.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I pray you're not using the code above literally -- you haven't escaped $nameser which means anyone who wanted to could come along and say ... delete your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you searched for a month and you haven't find anything that must be some kind of miracle
searched 2 seconds find plenty of results

http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html

http://www.exploremyblog.com/html/blog_contents.php?blogid=300

http://www.thewhyandthehow.com/jquery-autocomplete/

there are millions of them
for your code i would do something like this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example").autocomplete("./search.php");
  });
```

try it

```
$nameser = $_GET['q'];

$names = '';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM characters WHERE name LIKE '%".$nameser."%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $names .= $row[name]."\n"; }

echo $names;
```

Comment: I actually took a few minutes to test this (as I've never used the widget before) and the answer above is completely wrong -- a newline delimited list won't work - it expects json.

Comment: well i just followed what was said http://www.thewhyandthehow.com/jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: it did work all i had to do was changing 

 $("#search").autocomplete({ source: "./search.php"});


to

$("#search").autocomplete("./search.php");

Comment: Am sorry but i agree with Eric. Everything in those pages you just rapidly checked does not work for what i am saying here. Also the code you made does not work either.

Comment: I see you are using the autocomplete plugin. Does jqueryui not come with it when i download it?

Comment: OMG. Ok smack me on the head lol. How do i give you points Breezer.

Comment: hehe no problem press the big up arrow next to this answer :D

Comment: lol, its been 2 years since I answered this, it's not like I'm gonna check all my old answers everyday for broken urls... And as i were saying in my answer all you have to do is search for jquery autocomplete plugin you'll find an alternative for yourself instant

Answer (score 0):

Having never used the widget before I had to spend a few minutes playing with it. It seems your problem is most likely that you're not returning the found data in JSON format. In a simple test, I used the following as my 'search.php':

```
$ary[] = 'hi';
$ary[] = 'there';
$ary[] = 'world';

$o = json_encode($ary);
echo $o;
```

and it worked perfectly.

The HTML/Javascript I used was the sample page from the widget: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote.html  which I downloaded to my local server and of course fixed the paths to all the included libraries, etc in order to test it.